# Download file using selenium and headless chrome in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to download a file from a site, as an example using the thinkbroadband site. Have found multiple posts about this but none of the solutions seem to work. Am using chrome v73. Using this from one of the non working solutions I found

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": "/path/to/download/dir",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
})

chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': "/path/to/download/dir"}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)

driver.get('https://www.thinkbroadband.com/download')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-col"]/div/div/div[7]/p[2]/a[1]').click()
```

there's no error but there's also no file when the script exists

Comment: if you disablle the line add_argument --headless what can you see your code and driver do? It download the file?

Comment: it falls over with `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)`